# How can you create a sort of geometric sequence using numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy-ndarray

```
def nthgeo_function(nth):
    pow(2,nth)
#arithmetic sequence code
#make a list of values for n as n1,n2,n3... done
list_nth = list(range(1,1000))
nth_array = np.array(list_nth)

nthgeo = arr(np.typecodes, (nthgeo_function(nth) for nth in nth_array))

def m_function(nthgeo):
    print(nthgeo%m)
    m_function(nthgeo)
```

is my code.
I imported array as arr before, and am trying to get multiple outputs from multiple inputs accordingly, like a one to one function, where 2^n where n ranges from 1 to 1000 has mod m performed on it 1,000 times.

Currently i am just trying to get a geometric sequence array for nthgeo, but the error message `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` keeps showing up.

I don't really know... I started a day ago. I tried copying the format of

```
vals = array('i',[1,2,3,4,...1000]) *theoretically
newArr = array(vals.typecode, (anyfunction(a) for a in vals))
```

Comment: I take it you wrote import array as arr. Then your error is being thrown because your line nthgeo = arr(np.typecodes... ) is trying to treat the module array, which you have named arr, as a function. You rather want to write nthgeo = arr.array(np.typecodes... )

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you are trying to do. Your line '[I] am trying to get multiple outputs from multiple inputs accordingly' sounds like you want to take an array as input and then perform your function on every element.

I am not exactly clear on what your function is, because it sounds like you want to calculate the nth power of 2, but it also sounds like you want to do some sort of modular arithmetic.

I'll assume it's the first case. Then, what you want is a function that's taking inputs, and as output giving 2 to the input power. There's a lot of ways you could do this, the simplest would be some sort of list comprehension, which is like a neat 1-line for loop that Python is a big fan of. It would look like this:

```
def nth_power(input_list: list[Int]) -> list[Int]:
    return [2**n for n in input_list]
```

This gives you a list of numbers where each number is 2 raised to the power of the number in that place in the first list.

I think numpy arrays would also suit your needs well. Start now with a numpy array of the numbers you want, so presumably 0... 1000. This looks like:

```
input_list = np.arange(1000)  # generates the np.array([0... 999])
```

Then, you can just pass this to np.pow(), like this:

```
output_list = np.power(2, input_list)
```

Here, this will give `output_list` as

```
array([  1,   2,   4,   8,  16,  32,  64, 128, 256, 512], dtype=int32)
```

Hope that helps, feel free to ask if you need some clarification:)